# How to use XPath in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, xpath, cross-browser

I Have a web applicaton and now I want to improve it so it works in FireFox.  My problem is how to use XPath in a cross-browser manner.

I have this script:

```
var oXmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        oXmlDoc.async = "false";
        oXmlDoc.loadXML(document.getElementById(MasterObj + "txtMenu").value);
        var xmlNodes = oXmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/FormGeneratorEntity/GetMenu[TemplateID=" + obj.value + "]");
  var len = xmlNodes.length
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   alert(xmlNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode('Title').text)
}
```

And my xml string looks like this:

```
 <FormGeneratorEntity><GetMenu><Title>MyTitle</Title><Val>MyValue<Val/></GetMenu></FormGeneratorEntity>
```

How can I make this work in Firefox?

Comment: Did you tried to switch to css selectors and use jQuery or sizzle? XPath is not used a lot in browser javascript.

Comment: `ActiveXObject` is IE specific.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery? If so, it would be a much more browser-friendly solution.

Comment: yes,I use jquery in some where of my project.please let me know how could use xpath in jquery ,because the sample in net is so simple and didnt answer my problem!
thank you Juaan.

Comment: please consider my string XML is like this:
<FormGeneratorEntity><GetMenu><Title>MyTitle1</Title><Val>MyValue1<Val/></GetMenu><GetMenu><Title>MyTitle2</Title><Val>MyValue2<Val/></GetMenu></FormGeneratorEntity>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not "How to use XPath in Firefox", but "How to create a XML document from a string (in Firefox)".

The answer to that question is the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser), more specifically the `parseFromString` method:

```
oXmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content_string, "text/xml");
```

Implemented in your current code:

```
var oXmlDoc,
    content_string = document.getElementById(MasterObj + "txtMenu").value;
if (window.DOMParser) {
    oXmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content_string, "text/xml");
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    oXmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    oXmlDoc.async = "false";
    oXmlDoc.loadXML(content_string);
} else {
    // Not supported. Do something
}
```

If you're still looking for excellent documentation on XPath, have a look at the [Mozilla Developer Network: XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath).

Comment: thank you ,but it couldnt solved my problem,because I want something to do xquery for my xml string,with javascript or jquery.for example :

/FormGeneratorEntity/GetMenu[TemplateID=20]